# Can I make it so the keyboard from EditText doesn't pinch my display?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to add an EditText field to my current view, and its working. However, when I click in the field to type, the keyboard comes up from the bottom but doesn't overlap anything, it forces my View to squeeze into half of the size. It looks absolutely awful. Does anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity declaration in your Manifest, add the property `android:windowSoftInputMode`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
/>
```

`adjustPan` tells it not to resize your Activity's view, but rather to pan the content so your edit field stays in view.